# Slide Animation in ScrollView

Tags: android, animation

I have the following gui structure:

```
<ScrollView>
   <LinearLayout>
      <dynamic created view 1>
      <dynamic created view 2>
      ...
      <dynamic created view 3>
   </LinearLayout>
<LinearLayout>
```

Now I want alle the Views to dissapear by clicking on one of them, except the one who is clicked. This one is meant to move slowly upwarts on top of the LinearLayout and after arriving there, some new

I have done the following steps by clicking on "cnode":

```
//cnode is a control in container
//i store the top position
int top = cnode.getTop();
//then i remove all views in container
container.removeAllViews();
//now i want to readd cnode in container and it should be animated from top to 0
//but only from the point of vilibility, keep the ScrollView in mind...
//container.add(cnode ....

//after the animation I want to add some new controls         
for(int i = 1;i<nodes.size();i++)   {
       container.addView(nodes.get(i));
}
```

Does anyone know a proper way to achieve this effect?

Comment: I'm not sure, if i understand you right, but i think, what you searching is similar like this: http://developer.android.com/training/animation/layout.html

Comment: @ManuZi but he wants different animations - one for a single view and a different one for the rest. i don't think what you've written would suffice...

Answer (score 0):

do you want to remove or animate the views? or maybe both?

in any case, you need to go over all of the linearLayout's children (use "getChildAt" and "getChildCount") , and check : if the current view is the one you've clicked on, do the animation to the right (or don't remove it), and if not, do the animation to the left (or remove it).

if you wish to both animate the views and remove them, you should add a listener for the animations, so that at the end of each animation, it will remove the view . however, i think it will cause some weird things to occur, so i think it's best to just do the animations instead.

btw, why did you use a scrollView instead of listView ?